# How to build a FileReader and BufferedReader constructor in Java?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I am currently working on a project in where I am building a project that reads a file and counts the occurrence of words and other occurrences (like the amount of times the word "the" occurs) and such. I have seen many examples of FileReader and BufferedReader being used, but they are used in main and I wish to use it in a constructor in a another file like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TextParser {
    private FileReader fr;
    private BufferedReader br;
    private File file;
    private String line;

    public TextParser() {

        this.file = new File("textParser.txt");
        this.br = null;

            try {

            this.fr = new FileReader(file);
            this.br = new BufferedReader(this.fr);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (this.br != null) {
                        this.br.close();
                    }

                    if (this.fr != null) {
                        this.fr.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ee) {
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   
    }


}
```

In this same class, I wish to create each method that calculates the amount of occurrences, then call everything in main. Most of the examples I have seen does this in main directly, but can I use FileReader and BufferedReader in a constructor like this ? How would I go about testing this ?

Comment: a constructor is ment for initializing variables, thats what you basically do in your example. I think what you are doing is perfectly valid.

Comment: btw you cant use the FileReader and BufferedReader if you close them immediately after having initialized them. Its better to initialize the fr and br references with new objects inside each of the methods you want to create. And use Close-with-resources, That way the objects will be closed automatically for you. See this tutorial on how todo that http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/bufferedreader.html

Answer (score 0):

This is valid to execute this code in a constructor. If you want to use several times your BufferedReader, you will have to reinitialize it, for example with a new instanciation.

By the way, constructor should be for initializing purpose only. My advice is to initialize the BufferedReader and FileReader in the constructor, close them on the

```
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {}
```

method, which is called when garbage collector deletes the object, and do operations on the stream on your methods. If you have multiple uses of the stream, you can also create a method to reset it.

Comment: Instances of `AutoCloseable` are usually closed when garbage collected. Though I would recommend to make the class implement `AutoCloseable` then use it in a `try-with-resources` block.

Comment: `finalize` is now deprecated. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize-- Don't override `finalize`.

Comment: You're right, I was talking to Java 8.
He can't use a `try-with-resources` if he just wants to initialize the stream in the constructor and make actions in methods.